# Dimensionality problem with PyTorch Conv layers

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a neural network in PyTorch with some input signals. The layers are conv1d. The shape of my input is [100, 10], meaning 100 signals of a length of 10.

But when I execute the training, I have this error:
Given groups=1, weight of size [100, 10, 1], expected input[1, 1, 10] to have 10 channels, but got 1 channels instead

```
config = [10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100] 
batch_size = 1
epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
kernel_size = 1
    
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
            
        def __init__(self, config, kernel_size=1):
             super().__init__()
                
             self.config = config
                
             self.layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv1d(self.config[i], self.config[i + 1], kernel_size = kernel_size),
                    nn.ReLU()) 
                    for i in range(len(self.config)-1)])
         
             self.last_layer = nn.Linear(self.config[-1], 3)
             self.layers.append(nn.Flatten())
             self.layers.append(self.last_layer)
        
        
        
      def forward(self, x):
           
            for i, l in enumerate(self.layers):
                x = l(x)
            return x
    
    
def loader(train_data, batch_size):
     
  inps = torch.tensor(train_data[0])
  tgts = torch.tensor(train_data[1])
        
  inps = torch.unsqueeze(inps, 1)
  dataset = TensorDataset(inps, tgts)
  train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = batch_size)
        
  return train_dataloader
```

At first, my code was without the unsqueez(inps) line and I had the exact same error, but then I added this line thinking that I must have an input of size (num_examples, num_channels, lenght_of_signal) but it didn't resolve the problem at all.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Can you show your inference code with before/after shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nn.Conv1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) expects input with shape of form `(batch_size, num_of_channels, seq_length)`. It's parameters allow to directly set number of ouput channels (`out_channels`) and change length of output using, for example, `stride`. For conv1d layer to work correctly it should know number of input channels (`in_channels`), which is not the case on first convolution: `input.shape == (batch_size, 1, 10)`, therefore `num_of_channels = 1`, while convolution in `self.layers[0]` expects this value to be equal 10 (because `in_channels` set by `self.config[0]` and `self.config[0] == 10`). Hence to fix this append one more value to config:

```
config = [10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]  # as in snippet above
config = [1] + config
```

At this point convs should be working fine, but there is another obstacle in `self.layers` -- linear layer at the end. So if `kernel_size` of 1 was used, then after final convolution batch will have shape `(batch_size, 100, 10)`, and after flatten `(batch_size, 100 * 10)`, while `last_layer` expects input of shape `(batch_size, 100)`. So, if length of sequence after final conv layer is known (which is certainly the case if you're using kernel_size of 1 with default stride of 1 and default padding of 0 -- length stays same), `last_layer` should be defined as:

```
self.last_layer = nn.Linear(final_length * self.config[-1], 3)
```

and in snippet above `final_length` can be set to 10 (since conditions in previous brackets satisfied). To catch idea of how shapes in `conv1d` transformed take look at simple example in gif below (here `batch_size` is equal to 1):

[image]

Comment: Oh God, Thank you so much for your great answer. It's so clear.